# Why do I have house flies in my carport?

Tags: pest-control, pest

I bought my home in early September 2012. I noticed that flies were flocking around a light in my open air carport whether it was on or off. I tried a few products like fly tape, spray and a fly trap. Still no results. This continued through fall until temps dropped. This Spring I thought I would take preventive measures and cleaned my entire carport with Lysol including my garbage cans which are new. But still flies are flocking around this light. Its strange, they don't land on it that much as if there were some food source. They just fly around it all day until the sun goes down and even then there are a few stragglers. I would say at peak during the day there are about 150 to 200 flies. Why are they attracted to this area and What do I do to get rid of them?

Comment: Cluster flies...

Comment: They're probably not house flies. I'm guessing they are carport flies.

Comment: Is there anything in or above the light?

Comment: Longshot, are they actually bees with a hive there?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that these are not your regular house flies but instead something called a [cluster fly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_fly)?

[image]

I've seen these flies make a nuisance of themselves in the ceiling of one house of a friend.  He had to get it fumigated.  After that, no problems.

Is your carport right next to your house?  is the light attached to the carport or to the house?  Could there be a little nest in there somewhere?

Comment: They're little black flies... They don't look any different than common house flies as far as I can see. However I haven't really examined them closely. Defiantly  not bees. Carport is attached to the house. There is no nest in the light nor above it in the attic.

Comment: In that case it could just be a spot they like.  We used to get this problem at our back door.  There was very little air movement and it's not too hot they seemed to love it!  You could try putting a pyrethrim sprayer there for a while... they won't like that but then you'll have to keep topping up the sprayer.  That worked for us even though it's outside.

Comment: Flys are attracted to our light fixture under the carport, I have sprayed and sprayed; but they always come back. I will try your suggestion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things.

- Remove all trash/food from the area and clean with bleach - spray down the whole area
- fumigate - you need to bomb everything with bug spray.  Maybe a few times.  Lay it on.  Use all precautions and such (wear a mask).
- keep your trash far far away for at least a month.  Flies are attracted to trash and often lay eggs in the trash or close by.  You need to find another area to put your trash for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was not the light. It was standing water from a small sewer line leak right by my carport. Got the leak fixed and flies went away on their own.